# python igraph Error at fast_community.c:553

Tags: python-2.7, igraph

First, thanks for reading and possibly responding to this.

Now, the question:
I am on python 2.7, and I am getting this error when attempting to find communities in my graph using the fastgreedy algorithm:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-3b8456851658> in <module>()
----> 1 dendrogram = g_summary.community_fastgreedy(weights=edge_frequency.values())

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.pyc in community_fastgreedy(self, weights)
    959           in very large networks. Phys Rev E 70, 066111 (2004).
    960         """
--> 961         merges, qs = GraphBase.community_fastgreedy(self, weights)
    962 
    963         # qs may be shorter than |V|-1 if we are left with a few separated

InternalError: Error at fast_community.c:553: fast-greedy community finding works only on graphs without multiple edges, Invalid value
```

This is how I created my graph:

```
import igraph as ig
vertices = words  #about 600 words from a number of news articles: ['palestine', 'israel', 'hamas, 'nasa', 'mercury', 'water', ...]

gen = ig.UniqueIdGenerator()
[gen[word] for word in vertices]  #generate word-to-integer mapping as each edge has to be between integer ids (words)

edges = []
for ind in xrange(articles.shape[0]):  #  articles is a pandas dataframe; each row corresponds to an article; one column is 'top_words' which includes the top few words of each article.  The above list *words* is the unique union set of top_words for all articles.
    words_i = articles['top_words'].values[ind]  # for one article, this looks like ['palestine','israel','hamas']
    edges.extend([(gen[x[0]],gen[x[1]]) for x in combinations(words_i,2)])  #basically there is an edge for each pair of top_words in a given article. For the example article above, we get edges between israel-palestine, israel-hamas, palestine-hamas.

unique_edges = list(set(edges))
unique_edge_frequency = {}
for e in unique_edges:
    unique_edge_frequency[e] = edges.count(e)    

g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={"label": vertices}, edges=unique_edges, directed=False)
g.es['width'] = np.asarray([unique_edge_frequency[e] for e in unique_edge_frequency.keys()])*1.0/max(unique_edge_frequency.values())
```

And this is what throws the error:

```
dendrogram = g.community_fastgreedy(weights=g.es['width'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your graph contains multiple edges (i.e. more than one edge between the same pair of nodes). The fast greedy community detection won't work on such graphs; you have to collapse the multiple edges into single ones with `g.simplify()`.

It also seems like you are trying to set the `"width"` attibute of the edges based on how many edges there are between the same pair of vertices. Instead of constructing `unique_edges` and then `unique_edge_frequency`, you can simply do this:

```
g = Graph(edges, directed=False)
g.es["width"] = 1
g.simplify(combine_edges={ "width": "sum" })
```

This will simply create a graph with multiple edges first, then assign a width of 1 to each edge, and finally collapse the multiple edges into single ones while summing up their widths.